# C# Quartz Scheduler - reset a trigger

Tags: c#, triggers, quartz-scheduler, reset, quartz.net

I have a job and a trigger, and every x time the trigger triggers the job. Sometimes, I have another scenario that I want to trigger the job, for example, when a list count is 300. When the list count gets to 300 I trigger the job with this code:

```
Scheduler.TriggerJob(JobKey.Create("jobkeystring"));
```

When I do that, I want to stop the regular time trigger, and restart it again after the job is done (for example if the regular trigger is 3 minutes, and 1 minute passed but the job was triggered by the list count getting over 300, I want the regular time trigger to stop and start again from 0 after the job is done).

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The second Job needs to know the JobKey for the First Job, in order to Pause it

```
IScheduler.PauseJob(JobKey)
```

You can find the JobKeys with this code.

```
    private static void ShowJobs(IScheduler sched)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("ShowJobs : Start");
        GroupMatcher<JobKey> matcherAll = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup();
        Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> jobKeys = sched.GetJobKeys(matcherAll);
        foreach (JobKey jk in jobKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", jk.Group, jk.Name));
            IJobDetail jobData = sched.GetJobDetail(jk);
            if (null != jobData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", jobData.JobType.AssemblyQualifiedName));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ShowJobs : End");
        Console.WriteLine("");

    }
```

Note, you'll want to store the JobKey (of hte first job) in a .config file and not hard code it in.  The "ShowJobs" code is to help you locate the value.

I would have code in the second job look like this:

This is pseudo code...to give you the idea......not

Something like this:

```
  [PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class SecondJob : IJob        /* : IStatefulJob */ /* Error  43  'Quartz.IStatefulJob' is obsolete: 'Use DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute and/or PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute annotations instead. */
    {

        public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;
            /*
             * stateful jobs are not allowed to execute concurrently, which means new triggers that occur before the completion of the execute(xx) method will be delayed.
             * */

            JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            msg = string.Format("Start : SecondJob : JobKey='{0}' at '{1}'", key, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            Console.WriteLine(msg);

    string firstJob_JobKey = string.Empty; /* read from a .config file or other way to get it, do not hard code it) */

            try
            {

                                        if(null!=context)
                    {
                            if(null!=context.Scheduler)
                            {
                                context.Scheduler.PauseJob(firstJob_JobKey);
                            }
                    }

                    /* now call code to actually do the job stuff , which would be a common library that both FirstJob and SEcondJob code share to avoid duplicate coding */

            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                /* put in finally block so that it will resume....*/
                try
                {
                    if(null!=context)
                    {
                            if(null!=context.Scheduler)
                            {
                                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstJob_JobKey))
                                {
                                    context.Scheduler.ResumeJobs(firstJob_JobKey);
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }


            msg = string.Format("End : SecondJob : JobKey='{0}' at '{1}'", key, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        }
    }
```

As far as the "300", research PersistJobDataAfterExecution (PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute) to see how to persist a value that you can read later.